# How to use 'settingsToggleClassName' in Griddle

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, griddle

As settingsToggleClassName requires string input.
I am implementing this in the following way

```
let griddleBtnStyle = {
  background: 'red'
};
```

and using this style in here

```
  <Griddle
          useGriddleStyles={false}
          results={this.getGriddleData()}
          resultsPerPage={10}
          tableClassName='table'
          showFilter={true}
          settingsText={''}
          settingsToggleClassName='griddleBtnStyle'
          settingsIconComponent={
            <RaisedButton
              label='Columns'
              primary={true}
            />}
          showSettings={true}
        />
```

Now, settings button having this class griddleBtnStyle - But no changes occured when I implemented in this way.As per eg here button should be red but none has occred.

Can you tell me the right way to implement settingToggleClassName

Answer (score 0):

You have a minor error, you have written:

```
settingsToggleClassName='griddleBtnStyle'
```

You transfer to properties `settingsToggleClassName` `string` griddleBtnStyle, not variable `griddleBtnStyle` with value `'red'`. If you want transfer variable its should like this (**{}**):

```
settingsToggleClassName={'griddleBtnStyle'}
```

Update:
Sorry, i didin't saw the:

```
let griddleBtnStyle = {
  background: 'red'
};
```

I thougth `griddleBtnStyle` its a class.
So i thing the best solution will be define in CSS class name `griddleToggleBtn` like this:

```
.griddleToggleBtn {
    background-color: red
}
```

and transfer to propertie `settingsToggleClassName` class name string 'griddleToggleBtn':

```
settingsToggleClassName='griddleBtnStyle'
```

its should work

Comment: what do you mean writting filter?

Comment: Whitcik - Please look edited version, new info added at bottom- edit is peer review. same info below.....Tried solution mentioned by you but Raised Button element remains the same With solution settingsToggleClassName={'griddleBtnStyle'}.
I get <button type="button" class="griddleBtnStyle"> but element.style {} remain empty

I also tried settingsToggleClassName={griddleBtnStyle}. I makes class of button and object I get <button type="button" class="obj obj">

Really stuck . can you look again

Comment: So as i understand now...i should create a CSS file and place a class - griddleToggleBtn inside the CSS and use that as the value of settingsToggleClassName ... and there isn't a way to use a variable like griddleBtnStyle to change the style of settings button. Sorry I mentioning it here but what I want is to replace settings button in griddle with a Material UI button...is there any other way to do this

Answer (score 0):

Ignore `settingsToggleClassName`. You would only use that if you wanted to apply CSS style to the toggle button created by Griddle.  **BUT**, you aren't using that button - you are supplying your own, using `settingsIconComponent`. So, if you want to change the appearance of your RaisedButton, just set its properties and/or style... For example, to change background to red:

```
      settingsIconComponent={
        <RaisedButton
          backgroundColor="red"
          label='Columns'
          primary={true}
        />}
```

Comment: Implemented this intially but what remains is a border outside the the Raised Button Component.To get rid of that we need to add background: transparent and border: none to button element with class = settings, not able to get hold of that element I tried all style props available in raised button control... can you give any idea -- http://imgur.com/a/cfaX3